# OpenERP always displays inherited view instead of original

Tags: odoo

Original views:

```
<record id='view_1' model='ir.ui.view'>
    <field name="name">view.name</field>
    <field name="model">my.object</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="17"/>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        ...
    </field>
</record>
```

inherited view from the original:

```
<record id='view_2' model='ir.ui.view'>
    <field name="name">view.name</field>
    <field name="model">my.object</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="10"/>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="view_1"/>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        ...
    </field>
</record>
```

So what happens is OpenERP always displays the inherited view ignoring the priority value. Is this expected behaviour, or there's something else I am missing?

If this is the expected behaviour, then please read further :-)

I have `my.second.object` with `many2one` field to `my.object`, and when I want to create `my.object` from this field, I want to open a bit different form view of `my.object`. I am trying to create a different view just for that purpose, but as you see it doesn't work so easily (or does it?).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is the expected behavior. The priority of a view only serves to select the main view to  use when no specific view was requested. Inherited views are "patch views" that act like children of the view they inherit from, and may never be selected as "main views". They always apply on top of their parent view when that view is displayed.

If you want an alternative view for a certain model you should define a new stand-alone view that does not inherit from any other. If that view is meant to be used only in the context of the view of `my.second.object`, there are two common tricks to make OpenERP use it:

- Define it inline in the form view of `my.second.object`, as a child of the `<field>` element. This may not work in all OpenERP clients depending on the version, and works best for declaring inline form views for `o2m` lines, normally.
- Declare it as a stand-alone view with a low priority (e.g. 32) and put a magic context key in the `many2one` field of the `my.second.object` view that should use it. The magic key is in the form `<view_type>_view_ref`, and the value must be the XML ID of the desired view. This should work everywhere.

```xml
<!-- Example 1: inline form view -->
<form string="My second object">
   <field name="my_object_id">
       <form string="My object inline view">
           <field name="name"/>
       </form>
   </field>
 </form>

<!-- Example 2: explicitly ask for special view using magic key -->
<form string="My second object">
   <field name="my_object_id" context="{'form_view_ref': 'module.my_object_form2'}"/>
</form>
```

For reference, have a look at [this page](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/specify_view_to_use.html) of the OpenERP documentation that explains most of the options for making and using context-specific views.

> **NOTE:** If you have used form_view_ref and from form view if you have
>   any button which is opening another form view of some other model then
>   it will give you error . It will try to open the same form view you
>   have passed in form_view_ref for another model also.

Comment: Although neither of the two methods provide the __clean__ way to solve my problem, but it does answer my question. Cheers

Comment: @and3p: not sure what you expected as "the clean way" to solve your problem? Do you mean you thought OpenERP would behave differently or offer other options? Would you like to have a second kind of view inheritance that allows copying "main views" as well? Current system is designed to let modules extend each other cleanly, by doing spot-modifications of the views defined by their "parent", allowing all kinds of combinations.

Comment: Well, right now I had to create a duplicate (except for a few modifications) view of my 'main view' just to be used with `my.second.object`, what introduced code redundancy. I was hoping I wouldn't need to resort to code duplication if I used view inheritance, but as `Inherited views are "patch views"...` other options are not possible. Correct me if my understanding about view inheritance is wrong.

Comment: @and3p: yes indeed, view inheritance is not meant to allow copying+patching, but only patching at the moment. If there is a strong need to allow copying as well, we may introduce support for this in the framework. BTW there *is* one way to copy+patch, but it only works on a copied model (i.e. when using _inherit = 'model1' with _name = 'model2'). In that case the inherited view can be declared for model2 but can still inherit from a model1 view. And it won't be applied for model1 at all.

Comment: I think using <field name="mode">primary</field> allows you to keep both views side by side and display them separately.

Answer (score 1):

What "position" you defined in `<field name="field_from_original_view">`?

```
<record id='view_2' model='ir.ui.view'>
    <field name="name">view.name</field>
    <field name="model">my.object</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="10"/>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="view_1"/>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="field_from_original_view" position="after" (or before)>
            <field name="inherit1" />
            <field name="inherit2" />
            <field name="inherit3" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I used `replaced`, but is it relevant to my question? The problem is that OpenERP uses my inherited view even there where it should be using the original one.

Comment: Maybe when You use "replaced" OpenERP replaces original view with inherited?

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a possibility to make an inherited form the standard form of your model so that it will be presented automatically.

BUT If you look at a specific task --> open an inherited form view for a one2many field e.g.; there is. Set the context variable 'form_view_ref' to 'MODULE.VIEW_ID'.

```
<field name="myOne2ManyField" context="{'form_view_ref': 'myModule.myInheritedView'}/>
```

Still works with Odoo 9.0.