# Openerp - how to inherit a view and preserve the original?

Tags: odoo

Is there a way to make changes on a view using inheritance and preserve the original view unchanged?

Comment: In what sense are you asking? I mean are you talking abount xml file or you want to preserve original view and want to make new view?

Comment: I mean I inherited project.project. And I inherited its form view and added a new page to it, but now the new page is also visible in the original module view and I don't want that.

Comment: That is the work of inheritance in view. If you don't want to change original one, you should create whole new `project.project` form view.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10881321/2343488) explain how to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

for do this, you have to inherit the view, make changes according to your need and then make priority of that "new view" higher than the original one, to call new view at a specific place or menu, use `ir.actions.act_window.view`. for more details you can checkout "crm" module.

Cheers,
Parthiv

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit view like this without changing in original view

```
<record id="invoice_supplier_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.invoice.supplier.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_supplier_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="partner_bank_id" position="before">
                    <field name="amount_to_pay"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit the orm with the same name as the base, i was facing the same problem but it got fixed as i made the name of the inherited orm same as the inheriting orm. Fixed my probelm with original view.

Answer (score 0):

add primary

```
<field name="mode">primary</field>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks