# Odoo - copy view?

Tags: view, odoo, openerp-8

I have View that is accessed either from menu directly or from lead/opportunity form view. Now when you open such view it behaves the same.

When I open such view from menu. I want option `create="false"` to be enabled, to not allow create new records. But if do that, it also won't allow to create that record when it is access from lead/opportunity form views.

I read that there is no way to copy view (but that was said like more than few years ago - [OpenERP always displays inherited view instead of original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880535/openerp-always-displays-inherited-view-instead-of-original)) - like you can copy model and use it as new without changing anything for old one.

**Example**

To better understand what I mean you can read that link I provided or look at this example (its not for view, but for Odoo model. Well the principle is the same):

```
from openerp import models
class my_model2(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model2'
    _inherit = 'my.model1'
```

This way it creates new model, copies everything from `my.model1` had. And If I add anything new to `my.model2` it won't affect `my.model1`. Thats what want to do with views, but I don't know if it is even possible (on version 8.0)

The only way I see now is just to do hard copy of that view or in other way - duplicate view. But that is not good practice at all, because if I would need to change anything in one view, most probably I would need to do in duplicate and so on..

Answer (score 0):

this Odoo inheritance is correct:

```
from openerp.models import Model
class MyModel(Model):
    _name = 'My.Model'
    _inherit = 'res.user'
```

In the last example you are creating a new Object that inherit to res.user.

[the different openerp model inheritance mechanisms whats the difference between them and when shouldthey be used](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/how-to/developers-13/the-different-openerp-model-inheritance-mechanisms-whats-the-difference-between-them-and-when-should-they-be-used-46)

[Building a backend module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html)

Comment: You didn't understand my question. And you provided same example as I did. I was asking about copying view, not the model itself (I just gave that example, because you can do it with model)

Comment: Really sorry, maybe this link can help you https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/how-to-properly-copy-views-in-odoo-8-88126